# Google Dataflow seems to drop 1000th record

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-platform

I have set up a small test using Google Dataflow (apache-beam).  The use case for the experiment is to take a (csv) file and write a selected column to a (txt) file.

The code for the experiment is as listed below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import logging
import re

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.metrics import Metrics
from apache_beam.metrics.metric import MetricsFilter
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

class EmitColDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    first = True
    header = ""
    def __init__(self, i):
        super(EmitColDoFn, self).__init__()
        self.line_count =  Metrics.counter(self.__class__, 'lines')
        self.i = i

    def process(self, element):
        if self.first:
            self.header = element
            self.first = False
        else:
            self.line_count.inc()
            cols = re.split(',', element)
            return (cols[self.i],)

def run(argv=None):
    """Main entry point; defines and runs the wordcount pipeline."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input',
                        dest='input',
                        default='/users/sms/python_beam/data/MOCK_DATA (4).csv',
#                        default='gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
                        help='Input file to process.')
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                        dest='output',
                        default="/users/sms/python_beam/data/",
#                        required=True,
                        help='Output file to write results to.')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    # Read the text file[pattern] into a PCollection.
    lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)

    column = (lines
            | 'email col' >> (beam.ParDo(EmitColDoFn(3)))
            | "col file" >> WriteToText(known_args.output, ".txt", shard_name_template="SS_Col"))

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

    if (not hasattr(result, 'has_job')  # direct runner
        or result.has_job):  # not just a template creation
        lines_filter = MetricsFilter().with_name('lines')
        query_result = result.metrics().query(lines_filter)
        if query_result['counters']:
            lines_counter = query_result['counters'][0]

        print "Lines committed", lines_counter.committed
run()
```

The last few lines of sample 1 below:

```
990,Corabel,Feldbau,cfeldbaurh@deliciousdays.com,Female,84.102.162.190,DJ
991,Kiley,Rottcher,krottcherri@stanford.edu,Male,91.97.155.28,CA
992,Glenda,Clist,gclistrj@state.gov,Female,24.98.253.127,UA
993,Ingunna,Maher,imaherrk@army.mil,Female,159.31.127.19,PL
994,Megan,Giacopetti,mgiacopettirl@instagram.com,Female,115.6.63.52,RU
995,Briny,Dutnall,bdutnallrm@xrea.com,Female,102.81.33.24,SE
996,Jan,Caddan,jcaddanrn@jalbum.net,Female,115.142.222.106,PL
```

Running this produces the expected output of:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
/Users/sms/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2017.1/scratches/scratch_4.py
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
Lines committed 996

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now for the strange results.  In the next run, the number of lines is increased to 1000.

```
994,Megan,Giacopetti,mgiacopettirl@instagram.com,Female,115.6.63.52,RU
995,Briny,Dutnall,bdutnallrm@xrea.com,Female,102.81.33.24,SE
996,Jan,Caddan,jcaddanrn@jalbum.net,Female,115.142.222.106,PL
997,Shannen,Gaisford,sgaisfordr7@rediff.com,Female,167.255.222.92,RU
998,Lorianna,Slyne,lslyner8@cbc.ca,Female,54.169.60.13,CN
999,Franklin,Yaakov,fyaakovr9@latimes.com,Male,122.1.92.236,CN
1000,Wilhelmine,Cariss,wcarissra@creativecommons.org,Female,237.48.113.255,PL
```

But this time the out put is

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
/Users/sms/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2017.1/scratches/scratch_4.py
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
Lines committed 999

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Inspection of the output file shows that the last line was NOT processed.

```
bdutnallrm@xrea.com
jcaddanrn@jalbum.net
sgaisfordr7@rediff.com
lslyner8@cbc.ca
fyaakovr9@latimes.com
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'EditColDoFn' skips first line, assuming there is one instance of it for each file. When you have more 1000 lines, the DirectRunner creates two bundles : 1000 lines in first one, and 1 line in second. In a Beam application, the input might be split into multiple bundles for processing in parallel. There is no correlation to number of files and number of bundles. Same application can process terra bytes of data spread across many files.

`ReadFromText` has an option 'skip_header_lines', which you can set to 1 in order to skip header line in each of your input files.